# Serialize into Protobuf in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, postman, protocol-buffers

I have a GRPC application which expose an endpoint and take a GrpcRequest as parameter.

```
message GrpcRequest {
   google.protobuf.StringValue name = 1;
   google.protobuf.Timestamp startDate = 2;
}
```

I'm trying to generate a serialized request in C# to test it through Postman.
When serializing using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer, I get the following json :

```
{
  "name": "MyRequest",
  "startDate": {
    "seconds": 1702854000,
    "nanos": 0
  }
}
```

But due to the StringValue type, Postman expect this kind of format :

```
{
  "name": {
    "value" : "MyRequest"
    },
  "startDate": {
    "seconds": "1702854000",
    "nanos": 0
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way in C# to serialize the GrpcRequest into a Protobuf format which is compatible with Postman ?
Or is there a way in Postman to accept Json request ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you really need to work with protobuf manually? There is full-featured support, based on protobuf message descriptions with all the auto-gererated stuff for serialisation/deserialisation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Good catch. I wrote a code to subscribe directly to the Grpc client and it's easier. I just struggled a bit with an exception :
An error occurred while sending the request. Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection

Fixed using this line :
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy();